# Clickable elements too close together? Site is Mobile friendly on Mobile but not on Google Mobile Friendly Checkup

Tags: html, css

My Website homepage is not mobile friendly on Google mobile friendly Checkup but it is mobile friendly on Mobile devices.
This is the URL which is showing the problem.
https://www.sarkariresultsin.info/

I check it here on Google Offical Page: -
https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly

Is shows that your website is not mobile friendly.
**Errors are: -**

1. Clickable elements too close together
2. Viewport not set

I have remove and add all parts of page but where i find the problem is this part: -
Here on the page you will 9 columns like Latest Results, Admit Card, Latest and more.
These are 9 columns in a table structure in a `<section>` and when I remove this table from page than my page show that this is mobile friendly.

Can you please, fix this problem? Here, I'm not using Bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your website is that it is not responsive; add a few media queries here and there to make sure that your website looks usable in both portrait and landscape mode. Like you stated above, you should make it so that when to let's say, the height of the viewport is more than the width (in other words, as soon as it goes into portrait mode), then the # of columns displayed goes from 3 to 1. This is just an example, but it will most likely make your website more mobile-friendly.

Also, I would recommend, after a certain point, for the navbar to have a hamburger icon to evenly spread out links within your website. An example of this:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-morphing-hamburger-menu-with-css

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why the mobile layout of your site is not working is the lack of media queries and the absence of a viewport.

Add a media query after the main styles in your site's css file. Example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
   selector {
      /*styles*/
   }
}
```

Add the viewport to the `head` tag of your site. Example:

```
<head>
   ...
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries but first and foremost you need the viewport tag in the head meta information.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You should build 'mobile first' making sure elements look their best, work correctly, ensuring buttons are distinguishable from other buttons/content, and are simple enough to submit without accidentally submitting something else.

You then should use media queries to change sizes, positioning, hide/show elements depending on their larger screen sizes.
The reason for this is so mobiles/cell phones can download and process less to render the results for the end user. Most people use mobile phones when they're out of the house, they have smaller memory, less processing power and aren't always connected to higher speed internet like wifi. [Here's one of countless stats pages showing mobile phone internet usage.](https://www.broadbandsearch.net/blog/mobile-desktop-internet-usage-statistics)